# Вопрос по разработке бота (бд или классы)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, discord, discord.py

Хотелось бы разобраться и получить совета от более умных. Я пытаюсь создать своего бота, который будет сам вести игру "Мафия". Игра будет кастомная, то есть на определенную тематику. И смысл будет в том, что у каждого игрока будет своя роль, имеющая идентификатор (типа страна). Кроме того, каждая роль обладает своими навыками (кто-то узнает страну игрока, кто-то его прямую роль и т.д.
Ночью ходят и мирные, и мафия. Изначально я планировал сделать все через классы, но в процессе "думания" зародилась мысль о БД.

В связи с этим вопрос: как мне будет проще или как лучше делать, учитывая, что БД точно будет для ведения статистики игр и побед? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Почему вы противопоставляете классы и БД? Они вполне себе могут сосуществовать. Это как бы если вы спросили "я хочу сварить суп, мне лучше варить в кастрюле или гречневый". Классы это о том как организовать код, а БД это где хранить состояние, на случай если программу остановили или она аварийно вышла.

Answer (score 1):

Если бот изначально рассчитан всего на 1-2 сервера, то будет проще для хранения данных использовать `json`, так как с ним в каком-то смысле проще работать и он хранится просто в виде текста. Если бот делается под неопределенное множество серверов, то тогда больше подойдет база данных.

Для работы с `json` в `Python` есть встроенный модуль, который так и называется и подключить его можно так

```
import json
```

Примеры работы и документация [**здесь**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

---

Что же насчет классов - этот термин напрямую никак не связан с хранением данных, но, может быть имеет смысл использовать их, для создания игровых ролей мафии с уникальными свойствами.